# How to add custom code on the click of Today button with xtype: 'datefield'

Tags: extjs

How to add custom code on the click of Today button with xtype: 'datefield'

Like example : adding custom date after click on "Today" Button.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'From',
        name: 'from_date',
        maxValue: new Date()  // limited to the current date or prior
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @A1rPun suggests, here's an implementation that gets the button from the picker.

```
var picker = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Date', {
    anchor: '100%',
    fieldLabel: 'From',
    name: 'from_date',
    maxValue: new Date()
});
var field = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [picker]
});
picker.getPicker().todayBtn.on('click', function() { 
    alert('hello');
});
```

Comment: +1 This is awesome :) Even better than my solution. The `todayBtn` configuration isn't even in the docs!

Answer (score 0):

**This code will not prevent the default behaviour of the 'Today' button!**

```
{
    xtype: 'datefield',
    //...
    listeners:{
        afterrender: function(){
            this.getPicker().el
            .down("div.x-datepicker-footer")
            .down('a.x-btn')
            .dom
            .onclick = function(){
                console.log('hooked');
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see Saki's school :)

Answer (score 0):

After the datefield is rendered, you can get the todayBtn from the date picker object and change its handler. The example below shows how you can change the "Today" action to "Yesterday":

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fahdshariff/7hLdh8kh/)

```js
Ext.onReady(function() {
  showPanel();
});

showPanel = function() {
  Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 250,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Date field with "Yesterday" button',
    items: [{
      xtype: 'datefield',
      anchor: '100%',
      fieldLabel: 'Date',
      format: 'Y/m/d',      
      value: Ext.Date.subtract(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, 1),
      listeners: {
        render: function(dateField) {
          var picker = dateField.getPicker(),
            yesterday = Ext.Date.subtract(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, 1),
            selectYesterday = function() {
              this.setValue(yesterday);
              this.fireEvent('select', this, this.value);
              this.onSelect();
            };
          picker.todayBtn.setText('Yesterday');
          picker.todayBtn.setTooltip(Ext.String.format('{0} (Spacebar)',
            Ext.Date.format(yesterday, dateField.format)));
          picker.todayBtn.setHandler(selectYesterday, picker);
          picker.eventEl.addKeyListener(Ext.EventObject.SPACE, selectYesterday, picker);
        }
      }
    }]
  });
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.2.0-gpl/ext-all.js"></script>
```